# Google Cloud SQL off GAE

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Can we use [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-sql) off Google App Engine ?

I'm also looking for examples of its use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use the custom JDBC driver.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external
You should expect high latency since your client will not be colocated with the mysqld.

You can also use the JDBC driver for admin tools:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin_tools